# Auto-join all currently open channels in Irssi

Tags: irc, irssi

Is there a way to tell Irssi that I want to auto-join all of the channels that are currently open?

I want something like:

```
/channel add -auto <all my currently open channels>
/save
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://blog.goeswhere.com/2007/12/irssi-screening-guide/):

```
/alias addallchannels script exec foreach my \$channel (Irssi::channels()) { Irssi::command("channel add -auto \$channel->{name} \$channel->{server}->{tag} \$channel->{key}")\;}
```

Followed by:

```
/addallchannels
/save
```

Answer (score 9):

Irssi has had an [`/ADDALLCHANS`](https://github.com/irssi/irssi/blob/48375c3f900f56434441caa0161c0531fd0ce435/irssi.conf#L110) alias since at least July 2014 that does exactly what you want: add all currently joined channels to the auto-join list.

Specifically, the alias is defined as:
 `ADDALLCHANS = "SCRIPT EXEC foreach my \\$channel (Irssi::channels()) { Irssi::command(\"CHANNEL ADD -auto \\$channel->{name} \\$channel->{server}->{tag} \\$channel->{key}\")\\;}";`

You'll still want to call `/save` afterwards if you want the settings to persist.

Comment: Added 2014... found 2020! Thank you!

Comment: if you have saved all open channels to autojoin and want to remove one you have to either remove it manually in config or use this alias first before ADDALLCHANS and saving after:
 

`RMALLCHANS = "SCRIPT EXEC foreach my \\$channel (Irssi::channels()) { Irssi::command(\"CHANNEL REMOVE \\$channel->{name} \\$channel->{server}->{tag} \\$channel->{key}\")\\;}";
`